# How to test my website on ipad air

Tags: css

Is there is any way to test website on **IPAD AIR** only. Without having it.

Also what media queries i need to do for fixing **css** issues.

i found IPAD AIR is having resolution  of **2048x1536**

Can anybody help me out

Thanks

Comment: Look at the Chrome dev tools.

Comment: That's the native resolution, though. It will run at 1024x768 in @2x mode.

Comment: resolution and viewport sizes are different, that resolution will still display like it does on a regular ipad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many websites that provide this sort of service!

[This website (Mobilephoneemulator)](http://www.mobilephoneemulator.com/) does this service, it seems to support the Ipad Air at the resolution that you specified.

To use it, first select the rough size of your desktop monitor, then select 'Ipad Air' on the devices pulldown on the right. You can then navigate to your website using the url bar right below it.